# How to create a 0 dimension tf.Variable?

Tags: python, tensorflow

dimension tf.Variable. Before I did that via:

```
tensor = tf.zeros([0,], tf.float32) * (rank + 1)
w = tf.Variable(tensor.numpy().tolist())
```

however it says that `AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'` when I put these two lines in a new project.
I think it is because eager_mode is disabled in that project i am working on? Is there any way I can create the same Viriable directly without `numpy()`?

Comment: why did you disable eager execution?

Comment: i dont know the detailed reason and it's team decision.

Answer (score 0):

To create a tensor of dimension 0, run the following code

```
## rank 0
# Default name
rank_0_tensor = tf.constant(4, tf.int16) 
print(rank_0_tensor)
        
Output: tf.Tensor(4, shape=(), dtype=int16)
```

Reference: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/tensor